# How to get values in an array that shares an element with other arrays in a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this array that has other arrays in each key, it has the `product_id` keys in each of the sub arrays and their values are unknown. How do I get the total the value of the `item_quantity` keys that share the same `product_id` value?

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ([product_id] => 17 [item_quantity] => 4) 

        [1] => Array ([product_id] => 17 [item_quantity] => 4)

        [2] => Array ([product_id] => 18 [item_quantity] => 6) 
    )
```

I have no idea of which php function to use, but in a general term I would be "getting all item_quantity in the subarrays of an array where product_id in subarrays is the same".

**EDIT :** I think I missed that I also want to get the total of all the `item_quantity` of every unique `product_id`, that means that I want to not only get that of `17` but also of `18`.

Comment: The title just made my head explode...

Comment: lol, so sorry. Any idea  how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
$sum = array();

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if( !isset($sum[$value["product_id"]]) )
        $sum[$value["product_id"]] = 0;
    $sum[$value["product_id"]] += $value["item_quantity"];
}

print_r($sum);
```

In your case output will be

```
Array ( [17] => 8 [18] => 6 )
```

The `item_quantity` with same `product_id` will be added in the same offset in the `$sum`array.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i think i forgot to mention that it will have to return all the sums of every unique product id.

Comment: Yes it will return all the sums of `item_quantity` of every unique `product_id`.

Comment: Please how can I contact you outside of here? I need a mentor, If that's okay with you.

Comment: it returns `Array ( [17] => 10)` when I print_r($sum)

Comment: No, for some reason it returns `Array ( [17] => 10)`

Comment: The array I am passing to it is stored in the session: `$_SESSION["cart"]`, when I `print_r($_SESSION["cart"])` I get:

Comment: Contd: I get `Array ( 
    [0] => Array ([product_id] => 17 [item_quantity] => 4) 

    [1] => Array ([product_id] => 17 [item_quantity] => 4)

    [2] => Array ([product_id] => 18 [item_quantity] => 6) 
);`

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: I am a big idiot, I've been doing something horribly wrong, searching for a bug that doesn't even exist. Thanks bro, your solution works.